# Selecting specific styles with rvest

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

Is it possible to scrape only text with specific styles with rvest?

Example HTML:

```
<p>Lorem ipsum <span style="font-size: 15px">dolor</span> sit amet, <span style="font-size: 15px">consetetur</span> sadipscing <span style="font-weight: 400">elitr</span>, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam.</p>
```

I want to scrape only the text with `font-size: 15px`, but not the text within other `<span>`-tags.

One workaround I have tried is:

```
html %>% 
  html_nodes('span') %>% 
  str_subset('font-size: 15px')
```

However, it's not possible to use `html_text` after `str_subset` as it converts the html to strings. Any other ideas besides erasing the remaining tags manually?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look up the `html_attr` and `html_attrs` functions in the rvest package.

This example will find the nodes with the attribute you are looking for:

```
library(rvest)

html<-read_html('<p>Lorem ipsum <span style="font-size: 15px">dolor</span> sit amet, <span style="font-size: 15px">consetetur</span> sadipscing <span style="font-weight: 400">elitr</span>, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam.</p>')

nodes<-html %>%   html_nodes('span') 
nodes[html_attr(nodes, "style")=="font-size: 15px"]

#{xml_nodeset (2)}
#[1] <span style="font-size: 15px">dolor</span>
#[2] <span style="font-size: 15px">consetetur</span>
```

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I was looking for!